# Ionic 3 media scanner

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic3, gallery

Is there any working media scanner plugin for Ionic 3? I need it because:
when i remove image with File plugin from device, it deletes image content but not the whole file, but after restart file disapperas.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic or Cordova has its [file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) with which you can access the file system of your device. In Android devices, music files are usually stored in the the SD card or share space under a directory called “Images”.